# Why does vb.nets '=' operator evaluate different types this way?

Tags: vb.net

I am confused and cannot find information on the rules for how the '=' operator evaluates in vb.net, specifically when comparing different types.

```
Dim x as String = "1"
Dim y as Integer = 1
Dim z as Boolean = true
```

When I compare these types (whilst debugging the program) they evaluate as follows:

```
x = y (True)
y = z (False)
x = z (True)
```

Since x = y and x = z I would have expected y = z to be also correct.

I assume there is some conversions going on but I'm unsure of the specifics of how this works; since both CBool(y) and CBool(x) both evaluate as true.

Comment: Just don't EVER compare different types that way and you won;t have any issues.  Why would ever want to know whether two values of different types are equal when they can't possibly be equal by virtue of their being different types?  In order to test equality, one value will have to be converted to the type of the other first and you should NEVER rely on that being done the way you want implicitly.  ALWAYS perform an explicit conversion to the type you want and then compare two values of the same type.  If you set `Option Strict On`, as you always should, the code you posted wouldn't compile.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I understand that logic, and that's what I normally follow; I specifically got into this line of enquiry after visual studio told me that my cast was redundant after typing 'If Date = CDate(string)'. I was wondering how the '=' operator works exactly in vb.net to potentially avoid any problems in the future

Comment: I'd be very interested to know the specifics of that because I don't see how it could be unless you just converted back to a `String` again, or else had `Option Strict Off`.  Like I said, you should always have `Option Strict On` so the question of how the comparisons you showed behaved should never be an issue because they are all illegal in that case.

Comment: @jmcilhinney sigh. after you said that I scrolled to the top of the file and there it is `Option Strict Off`. I was working on somebody elses file from git! I've spent all afternoon scratching my head and its down to that! damn

now I've got some co-workers to be annoyed at! haha

Comment: But then again, does Option Strict Off affect the watch tab / immediate window? I was testing this theory out there as well and it mirrors what i put in the above post. At least it underlines the line `If Date = String` as incorrect and won't build

Comment: To make the comparison work, the compiler has to generate code to convert the Boolean to Integer.  Which doesn't work the way you assume, add `Console.WriteLine(CInt(True))` to see what happens.  Compatibility with earlier Basic versions, using -1 to represent True was useful to hide the difference between bitwise and logical And/Or operators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things at play here:

1. A numeric-and-string situation with various operators (such as =, +, -, *, /, etc.) will get translated into a respective numeric-and-numeric overload. E.g. `"1"=1` compiles as `CDbl("1")=CDbl(1)`.
2. For historic reasons, the Boolean of `True` is mapped to Integer of `-1`. Hence True=1 is False; but True=-1 is True.

This numeric-and-string thing can be shutdown via `Option Strict On`, or put under more granular control via Warning Configuration "Implicit conversion" (of the Project Properties window, Compile tab). Yep, it's strange, other BASICs (such as QBasic or QuickBasic) don't do this, but way back when Visual Basic was being developed (the first generation VBA/VB6, that is) it somehow seemed a good idea at the time. I'd bet it's connected with VBA being the stored procedure language (if you will) of Microsoft Access; translating numeric-and-string to the respective numeric-and-numeric overload certainly happens in the SQL dialects of MS SQL Server, Oracle, and DB2. Give it a try and see for yourself - e.g. in SQL Server:

```sql
declare @x varchar(250) = '1',@y int = 1
Select (Case When @x=@y Then 1 Else 0 End)
```

As for True being -1 when converted to integer, that goes way back to Altair BASIC (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altair_BASIC). It's a trick to let AND and OR and especially NOT to work as expected for contexts of logical operations (and not bit-wise operations). To clarify, AND/OR/NOT were indeed bit-wise operators - e.g. NOT 1 = -2. So for something like `Not True` to result as `False` (which is 0), `True` has to be -1. Altair BASIC through VBA/VB6 do not have bona fide logical operators - logical operations in them are emulated via bit-wise operations on integers. VB.NET, however, does have bona fide logical operators, but of course care must be taken with integers since it'll do legacy behaviors on them.

The official language reference is at https://github.com/dotnet/vblang/blob/master/spec/README.md. At https://github.com/dotnet/vblang/blob/master/spec/expressions.md, there are grids captioned with "Operation Type" that indicate this behavior - although perhaps to subtly.